# What is this "consumption and fever"?

Tags: leviticus

In Leviticus 26:16 (NASB)

> I, in turn, will do this to you: I will summon a sudden terror against you, **consumption and fever that will make the eyes fail and the soul languish**; also, you will sow your seed uselessly, for your enemies will eat it.

What is this "consumption and fever"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word translated "consumption" by NASB is שַׁחֶפֶת (shachepheth) which just means "wasting disease" (BDB) of which the most common was "consumption".  Note the explanation from Wikipedia about tuberculosis -

> **Tuberculosis** (TB) is an infectious disease usually caused by
> Mycobacterium tuberculosis (MTB) bacteria.[1] Tuberculosis generally
> affects the lungs, but can also affect other parts of the body.[1]
> Most infections show no symptoms, in which case it is known as latent
> tuberculosis.[1] About 10% of latent infections progress to active
> disease which, if left untreated, kills about half of those
> affected.[1] The classic symptoms of active TB are a chronic cough
> with blood-containing mucus, fever, night sweats, and weight loss.[1]
> It was historically called **consumption due to the weight loss**.

The word שַׁחֶפֶת (shachepheth) only occurs in Lev 26:16 and Deut 28:22.  In Lev 26:16, it is mostly translated, "wasting disease" by most modern versions.

The LXX translates it this way (Brenton) -

> then will I do thus to you: I will even bring upon you perplexity and
> the itch, and the fever that causes your eyes to waste away, and
> [disease] that consumes your life; and ye shall sow your seeds in
> vain, and your enemies shall eat them.

That tuberculosis (consumption) was a wasting disease, it is not the only one.  There are many such and Lev 26:16 does not specify which particular one.